# Combined Chart mpAndroidChart

Tags: android, kotlin, mpandroidchart

I am currently creating a chart to display statistics.
The problem is that on the combinedChart I can't display the lineDataChart
[image: graph I get]
The expected result is this [image: expected graph]

The second image is the superposition of a barChart and a lineChart but the problem is i can't use properly the scroll mode because it will only scroll on one graph.
Here is the code for the first graph

```
class GraphCombinedChart (context: Context) : CombinedChart(context, null, 0) {

    private var chart: CombinedChart? = null

    private fun dtoToBarEntry(floats: List<Float>?) : ArrayList<BarEntry> {
        return ArrayList<BarEntry>().apply {
            floats?.forEachIndexed { index, fl ->
                add(BarEntry((index + 1).toFloat() , fl))
            }
        }
    }

    private fun dtoToEntry(floats: List<Float>?) : ArrayList<Entry> {
        return ArrayList<Entry>().apply {
            floats?.forEachIndexed { index, fl ->
                add(Entry((index + 1).toFloat() , fl))
            }
        }
    }

    fun setupChart(
        values: List<PlayerGraphStatModel>?,
        landScapeMode: Boolean = false
    ) {

        val indexPerformanceList = dtoToEntry(values?.map { it.timePlayed.toFloat() }?.plus(values.map { it.timePlayed.toFloat() }))
        val timePlayedList = dtoToBarEntry( values?.map { it.indexPerf }?.plus(values.map { it.indexPerf }))
        val entryData = LineData(LineDataSet(indexPerformanceList, "").apply {
            color = Color.White.hashCode()
            setDrawValues(true)
        })
        val barEntryData = BarData(BarDataSet(timePlayedList, "").apply {
            color = Color.AiaRed.hashCode()
            setDrawValues(false)
        })

        val combinedData = CombinedData()
        combinedData.setData(barEntryData)
        combinedData.setData(entryData)

        chart = this
        formatChart(combinedData, landScapeMode)
        configureXAxis()
        configureYAxis()
        chart?.renderer = BarChartRenderer(chart, chart?.animator, chart?.viewPortHandler)
    }

    private fun formatChart(combinedData: CombinedData, landScapeMode: Boolean = false) {
        val barWidth = 0.75f

        chart?.drawOrder = arrayOf(
            DrawOrder.LINE,
            DrawOrder.BAR,
            DrawOrder.LINE,
        )
        chart?.data = combinedData
        chart?.description?.isEnabled = false
        chart?.legend?.isEnabled = false
        chart?.barData?.barWidth = barWidth
        chart?.animateY(1000)
        chart?.isDoubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
        chart?.setScaleEnabled(false)
        chart?.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = true
//        barChart?.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(8f)
//        barChart?.moveViewToX(0f)
        if (!landScapeMode) {
            chart?.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(8f)
            chart?.moveViewToX(11f)
        }
        chart?.resetViewPortOffsets()
        chart?.resetZoom()
        chart?.notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    private fun configureXAxis() {
        chart?.xAxis?.apply {
            setDrawGridLines(false)
            setDrawAxisLine(false)
            setDrawLabels(true)
            position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
            valueFormatter = MyXAxisFormatter()
            granularity = 1f
            labelRotationAngle = +0f
            textColor =  Color.White.hashCode()
            textSize = 12f
            textAlignment = TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
            axisMinimum = data.xMin - 0.75f
            axisMaximum = data.xMax + 0.75f
            disableScroll()
        }
    }

    private fun configureYAxis() {
        chart?.axisRight?.apply {
            setDrawGridLines(false)
            legend?.isEnabled = true
            isEnabled = false
        }
        chart?.axisLeft?.apply {
            setAxisMinValue(0f)
            setAxisMaxValue(100f)
            valueFormatter = MyLeftAxisFormatter()
            setDrawGridLines(true)
            setDrawAxisLine(true)
            textColor = Color.White.hashCode()
            textSize = 14f
        }
    }

    inner class MyXAxisFormatter : IndexAxisValueFormatter() {

        override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
            return "${value.toInt()}"
        }
    }

    inner class MyLeftAxisFormatter : IndexAxisValueFormatter() {

        override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase?): String {
            return "${value.toInt()}"
        }

    }

}
```

I have checked and the data is not empty.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm not able to replicate this. Also, `chart.axisRight.legend` does not exist (in MPAndroidChart 3.1.0 at least - `legend` is only a property of the chart, not the axis). What version are you using?

Comment: I'm currently using version 3.1.0.
Thanks I'm going to look this !